# QT when I try to link to a dll, undefined reference error occurs

Tags: c++, qt

I build a cm-lib.dll

```
QT       -= gui
TARGET = cm-lib
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += c++14
DEFINES += CMLIB_LIBRARY
......
```

### .h file

```
#ifndef MASTERCONTROLLER_H
#define MASTERCONTROLLER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>

#include "cm-lib_global.h"

namespace cm{
namespace controllers{

class MasterController : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString ui_welcomeMessage  MEMBER welcomeMessage CONSTANT)
public:
    explicit MasterController(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    QString welcomeMessage = "This is MasterController to Major Tom";

signals:

public slots:
};

}}

#endif // MASTERCONTROLLER_H
```

### .cpp file

```
#include "master-controller.h"

namespace cm{
namespace controllers{


MasterController::MasterController(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    int i = 1;
    i = i +1;
}

}}
```

### When I try to link it in another main file, ld error

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include <controllers/master-controller.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<cm::controllers::MasterController>("CM",1,0,"MasterController");

    cm::controllers::MasterController masterController(NULL);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("masterController",&masterController);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/views/MasterView.qml")));

    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

### error message

D:\WORKC\QT\cm\cm-ui\source\main.cpp:18: error: undefined reference to `cm::controllers::MasterController::MasterController(QObject*)' D:\WORKC\QT\shadow-builds\cm-ui\debug\main.o:-1: In function` Z15qmlRegisterTypeIN2cm11controllers16MasterControllerEEiPKciiS4_':
C:\Qt\Qt5.10.0\5.10.0\mingw53_32\include\QtQml\qqml.h:285: error: undefined reference to `cm::controllers::MasterController::staticMetaObject' C:\Qt\Qt5.10.0\5.10.0\mingw53_32\include\QtQml\qqml.h:308: error: undefined reference to` cm::controllers::MasterController::staticMetaObject'

......

Comment: Did you add something like `win32:QMAKE_FLAGS += /LIBPATH:the/path/to/the/dir/where/cm-lib.lib/is/located` and `win32:LIBS += cm-lib.lib` to the .pro file of the program you want to link to your library?  If not, then that program won't know to link to cm-lib.lib and therefore you'll get unresolved-symbol errors when trying to link to functions defined in the library.

Comment: INCLUDEPATH += source \
          ../cm-lib/source

the parth is right:
SOURCES += source/main.cpp
RESOURCES += views.qrc
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../binaries/$$DESTINATION_PATH -lcm-lib

Comment: How are you adding your cm-lib.dll to the project compiling main.cpp? Could you share the snippet of that .pro file?

Comment: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../binaries/$$DESTINATION_PATH -lcm-lib   the path is right!

Answer (score 1):

```
class CMLIBSHARED_EXPORT MasterController : public QObject
```

when I add `CMLIBSHARED_EXPORT` to the class definition，Problem solved！